# How to make bash script behave the same in console and without it

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I have a simple script that I use to turn off a second screen. It works when used from console `./togglemon.sh` but if i double click it and choose to run it nothing happens - why and how to fix it?

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr|grep "DVI-D-0 connected 1080"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
   xrandr -s 1
else 
   xrandr -s 0
fi
```

Comment: Add full path to xrandr and grep.

Comment: Is the space before the `#!` there in your real script? The `#` in a shebang needs to be the *very first byte* of your file.-

Comment: And BTW, use `if xrandr | grep -q "DVI-D-0 connected 1080"; then` -- there's no reason whatsoever to run a second `[` command when you could just have `if` branch directly on the exit status of `grep`.

Comment: Beyond that, frankly, we *can't tell* why with only the information given; we'd need to see what's going on on your specific machine. Maybe the PATH is different between the environments, maybe the DISPLAY is different, maybe... etc, etc, etc.

Comment: `export DISPLAY=':0'` at start of script could help.

Comment: Another very good place to start is to log to a file. `exec 2>>~/togglemon.log; set -x` as the 2nd line, and then you'll have logs from the rest of the script, which will have "command not found" errors if Cyrus's guess is correct.

Comment: @LéaGris, ...or could hurt, depending; if it overrides a correct DISPLAY variable with a faulty one, that makes things worse, not better. I'd want to see an actual error message before deciding on a course of action. At minimum, it's probably sensible to override `DISPLAY` *only if it's actually unset before*.

Comment: the export DISPLAY is only available for the running script and childs of it anyway. It cant hurt. Otherwise `xrandr --display :0` specifying the display to work with is also an option.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 1. not typo here, 2 i know I can make it without that ` if [... ]` it was just `if (xrandr | grep -q "DVI-D-0 connected 1080")` fiddling with it to make it work

Comment: for reference I started with that:
`(xrandr|grep "DVI-D-0 connected 1080") && xrandr -s 1 ||xrandr -s 0)` -and again - it works when I start it from the terminal but doesn't work if I double click it in nautilus and choose run.

Comment: @LéaGris, the case where it can hurt is where your correct `DISPLAY` is not `:1` but `:2`, or `:127.0.0.1::10089` or some other thing. Setting `DISPLAY=:1` would thus (yes, only for that one process and its children) overwrite the already-correct value, thus preventing `xrandr` from running successfully, even if the OP's real problem, whatever it is, was fixed.

Comment: @Lord_JABA, don't use the extra parenthesis; they have a performance cost: `(foo)` in bash is slower than `foo` because it does an extra `fork()`, creating a subprocess and running `foo` inside it. There's no reason to pay that cost for your use case at hand.

Comment: @LéaGris no difference

Comment: @Lord_JABA, ...anyhow, earlier in this thread I told you how to generate a log file. When you do that, and then double-click from Nautilus, and go back and read the log, what's in it? Right now everyone just has a bunch of different, competing guesswork; having a log with a specific failure would let us stop guessing and start diagnosing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy whane ran  from terminal I get log with :

     `++ xrandr
++ grep 'DVI-D-0 connected 1080'
++ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
++ xrandr -s 0`
 

if I run from nautilus no log created.  same if i create .desktop shortcut to that script - nothing happens

Comment: Give the log when run by clicking on it.  Like Charles Duffy said, add `exec 2>>~/togglemon.log; set -x` as the second line to your script. Then run it (by double-clicking on it) Then cite that log here.

Comment: Okay, if the log isn't being created (and you followed my example and forced an absolute path so you're not just expecting it to be created in a directory other than where it really is) I'd probably go from there is to trace execution with `sysdig`, `bpftrace`, or similar tooling that let you follow syscalls across the entire system; that way you can see exactly what nautilus is doing and where it fails.

Comment: ...that said, if you're just assuming that the current directory Nautilus runs your script with is the same as the directory your script is in, that's not necessarily a well-founded assumption, so before going to the point of using system-wide trace tools, I'd make sure you're fully-qualifying your PATH.

Comment: Does your Nautilus actually allow you to run scripts by double-click?  Refer to Nautilus' preferences. Also see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - finally have some free time so im recycling the topic, how can i make sure PATH is " fully qualifying" - I don't understand the term? Are you asking if I' using absolute paths in the script? ... icon would be so much more convenient

Comment: I yes then i tried it both with /usr/bin in front of xrandr and grep and without it - works the same

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just noticed "Nautilus" - im Using KDE so not nautilus but Dolphin